# Pass the password to the openssl command that generates the keystore

Tags: ssh, openssl, automated-tests

I have the following command that  transform the certificate and private key from PEM to pkcs12 format and store them in a keystore

> openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out
> keystore.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem

This command is sent via SSH and the terminal responds with requesting a password for the store which I can not respond to from my remote tool
I tried this but did not work

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out keystore23.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem -storepass somepass
```

Any of the following solutions would suffice :

1- Send the password directly by passing an argument to the openssl tool
2-  Send the password to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

if your'e using linux you can use pipelines.

> A Unix pipe connects the STDOUT (standard output) file descriptor of
> the first process to the STDIN (standard input) of the second.

so the command will be:

```
echo <password> | openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem
```